# How do I make my synclient settings stick?

Tags: touchpad, settings

The default setting for synaptics touchpads includes a paste functionality mapped to the upper right corner of the touchpad. I can disable this behavior by running the command

```
synclient RTCornerButton=0
```

But every time I reboot my settings are reverted. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 21):

You need to put the settings in a xorg.conf file as follows:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-synaptics-options.conf
```

In the new file, type

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "touchpad catchall"
  Driver "synaptics"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

  Option "RTCornerButton" "0"

EndSection
```

Comment: You shouldn't make local changes to files in /usr/share. Instead put the new file under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/.

Comment: @jdthood [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/126539/73423) suggested editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: How do I know what number I should put in the file name, according to my distribution (Ubuntu 16.04)? Some say `60-synaptics-options.conf`, other say `50-`, `51-`...

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong The number starting the file name indicates the order in which the configuration files are applied; lower numbered files are applied first.

Comment: @jdthood There's no such directory /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d ...

Comment: @AkseliPalén That answer *seems* to be saying I should *create* that file if it doesn't exist... but why doesn't it, if it's the file to use?

Comment: @Michael presumably, X11 scans that directory on login and executes any files in there.

Answer (score 13):

Gnome settings daemon may override existing settings (for example ones set in xorg.conf.d) for which, the existing settings in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` are being ignored.
This is how i fixed it.

> Run `dconf-editor`
>
> Edit `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/` (or
>   `/org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/` for cinnamon)
>
> Uncheck the `active` setting

It will now respect your system's existing synaptics configuration.

Then follow [monkbroc's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/293748/211871) which will work now.

Comment: Iam using budgie-desktop on top of gdm, but even after this my settings get overriden....

Comment: Dear god this took me so long to find. Thanks for the answer it was exactly the bane of all my problems.

Comment: @cra0zy, the literal needle in the haystack, eh?

Comment: I found on Ubuntu 18.04 that something still overrides my conf settings even with the `dconf-editor` solution. So, I instead added a script to `/etc/profile.d/` that sleeps 10 seconds before applying the settings: `(sleep 10; synclient TapButton2=3) &`.

Answer (score 9):

(Maybe) the fastest workaround is to create an entry in the "Startup Applications". It could be found in the unity launcher.

An example entry looks something like this:

Name: `Enable Palm Detection`

Command: `synclient PalmDetect=1`

Comment: `Enable synclient palm detection`

This is essentially equivalent to Augustin Riedinger's answer, but instead of creating the desktop entry manually, we let Ubuntu to do it for us.

Comment: This is not working in MATE

Comment: This works also fine in Gnome 3. Thanks a lot !

Comment: not working, Xubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 9):

The best method that have worked for me is to add your changes into Xsession.d, so it will load automatically for all users when you log into X:

(the file doesn't exists, so you can name it whatever you want. The numbers on the left means the order in which it will be executed in comparison with the other files.)

`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/80synaptics`

(owned by root, with permissions 644)

For example, you can use this as base:

```
#https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics
#Palm dimension
#synclient PalmDetect=1
#synclient PalmMinWidth=4
#synclient PalmMinZ=100

#Touchpad sensibility (move)
#synclient FingerLow=10
#synclient FingerHigh=20

#Click detection
#synclient MaxTapTime=180
#synclient MaxTapMove = 242
#synclient MaxDoubleTapTime = 180

#2 finger = right click
#synclient TapButton2=0
#3 finger = middle click
#synclient TapButton3=2
#click corners
#synclient RBCornerButton=0 MaxTapTime
#synclient RTCornerButton=0
#synclient LTCornerButton=0
#synclient LBCornerButton=0

#Oval instead of rectangular
#synclient CircularPad=1

#TapAndDragGesture
#synclient TapAndDragGesture=1

#scroll in sides
#synclient VertEdgeScroll=0
#synclient HorizEdgeScroll=0
#synclient CornerCoasting=0

#2 finger scroll
#synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
#synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0

#Disable Touchpad on start
#synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

Comment: When I do that, and uncomment some stuff like the 2 finger and 3 finger tap, it does not work after I reboot. But it does when I manually enter them in terminal. So what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @Mason: Are you sure there is not a syntax error (perhaps some strange character introduced if you 'copy-pasted' the code)? Check the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` log file for errors or warnings.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, it was probably the most promising answer as well.  I logged off and back in to find that the file was still there and the uncommitted line was the way I set it.  But I still had to run the command in the terminal to see it work correctly.

Comment: @Chris: It is still working for me in 16.04. I will test it in a clean installation and let you know here (probably there is something I set long time ago that makes it work for me).

Comment: @lepe Thanks for checking into it.  I ended up using the "Application Autostart" answer (2 down right now).  That seems to work reasonably well.  I'm trying to stop the whole TapAndDragGesture garbage.  Even after setting it to 0, I still get a small window where it'll still do that.  Perhaps this technique would work better, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

### Make `synclient` options stick between X sessions

**Using `startx` ([xinit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xinit))**

Add any `synclient <option>=<value> &` lines to `.xinitrc` *before the line which runs your window manager or desktop environment*, like so:

```
## ~/.xinitrc
## X11 startup script; sourced by xinit(1) and its frontend startx(1)

## Set Synaptics touchpad options
synclient RTCornerButton=0 &

## Start desktop environment or window manager of your choice
exec startxfce4
# exec startlxde
# exec startkde
# exec i3
# exec dwm
```

The above example sets `synclient` options before running the [Xfce](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions/XFCE) desktop environment.
Lines beginning with `#` are **comments** (they will not be executed).

**Using a display manager**

The method is the same as for `xinit`, except you put the `synclient` lines in a relevant startup script for your display manager, e.g. `/etc/GDM/Init/Default`.

If you have any doubts, let me  refer you to the excellent [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostart). Even though its Archlinux-specific, most solutions work in every linux distro due to Arch's DIY nature. Have a good one!

Comment: Won't work either ...

Comment: Output of `synclient; synclient RTCornerButton=0; synclient`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and this may not work for you. Open Session and startup or whatever the name is for you.
Go to Application Autostart tab, again whatever the name is for you.
Click the add button.
Keep whatever name and description you want to and in the command type:

```
synclient RTCornerButton=0
```

If you want to add multiple lines separate them with a `;`

Make sure the command you just created is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Add `synclient [Var=Value]` to the end of ~/.bashrc

example: `synclient RTCornerButton=0`

This will make you system set this synclient setting every time you log in.

Comment: This doesn't work ... The params are executed when a bash is launched, not on session open ...

Answer (score 1):

try touchegg, this solution worked on my XPS13 Ubuntu16.04
https://samtinkers.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/3-finger-gestures-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions suggested here don't work for me:

- I want the config to be in the `/home` folder as it is local config (so I can keep the parameters even if I change my distrib for instance)
- `.bashrc` or `.xinitrc` don't seem to be executed correctly

So I ended up creating a `.desktop` file that is autostarted:

```
cat ~/.config/autostart/touchpadconfig.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Touchpad Config
GenericName=Touchpad Config
Comment=Sets better default parameters to touchpad
Exec="synclient VertScrollDelta=40 && synclient AccelFactor=0.1 && synclient RightButtonAreaTop && synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=0"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=input-mouse
Categories=Settings;
StartupNotify=false
```

Maybe not the best solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity desktop. To make the settings permanent, I had to paste the synclient commands to a shell script and add the shell script to my Startup Applications in Unity.

Note: The shell script must start something like `#!/bin/bash` before the synclient commands, and the permissions have to be changed to executable.

Answer (score 0):

With Wayland (still experimental in 17.04, but soon to be the default), you have all the setting you need:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
sudoedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

add those lines in the Section "InputClass"

```
Option "RTCornerButton" "0"
```

If you're using GNOME or Cinnamon desktop manager, there is a good chance that GNOME/Cinnamon's settings can override your custom settings. To prevent GNOME/Cinnamon's settings override yours, open **dconf Editor** [`dconf-editor`] and edit following entry:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/
or
/org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/
```

Uncheck **active**.