# How do I enable mouse momentum after release in kde/gnome/unity?

Tags: mouse, kde, synaptics

I mostly use kde, and I've loved it but I recently tried an hp laptop with all the synaptics suite and I played with it a bit and tried the mouse momentum feature, where the cursor continues after releasing the trackpad. I'm hooked, I want that feature in kde if it means PAYING for it, I seriously found it to be such an aesthetically pleasing feature that there is no way I want to just deal with not having it. Can someone either tell me how I can get the same thing natively or how to port/hack-onto-my-system synaptic configure tool/whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Synaptics touchpad, the relevant settings are `CoastingSpeed` and `CoastingFriction`. My settings are:

```
# synclient -l
...
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
```

Try it out with

```
synclient CoastingSpeed=20 CoastingFriction=50
```

Adjust the values till you find it comfortable.
Look at [How do I make my synclient settings stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290009/how-do-i-make-my-synclient-settings-stick-ubuntu-13-04) for instructions on making the seetings permanent.

Comment: I'm sorry but that seems to be for scroll speed, I want the cursor itself to coast. I said it seems to be for scroll because it made no difference on the cursor no matter how much I change it, or it just does not work in kde.

Comment: Ah. This does only affect scrolling. The content continues to scroll after you have left the touchpad, which is close to, but not, the effect you want. I'll look around for other options.