# Xubuntu 14.04 black screen after modifying xorg.conf file

Tags: 14.04, boot, xubuntu, touchpad

Wanted to decrease the sensitivity of my touchpad *and* have the setting remain after boot up.  Follow [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290009/how-do-i-make-my-synclient-settings-stick) (caveat: I added two "Options" lines for Finger sensitivity and noise cancellation), I made an xorg.conf file.

Now on boot up, I arrive at a black screen with a cursor that is not blinking.  I briefly see the Xubuntu start page before it goes black, but then nothing.

For reference, I'm dual booting Xubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 1550.

Answer (score 1):

Try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> after you boot in Ubuntu. The combination launches `tty console`, you may recover configuration.

Comment: The OP probably used a GUI editor to change xorg and may not know a text based editor. If possible you could improve your answer with simple instructions to start, open file, edit, save and quit a text based editor. Then to restart xorg or `sudo reboot` from the console.