# Disabling corner buttons permanently

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I am using Xubuntu 17.10. I am really annoyed by the corner functions of the touchpad. I want to disable them permanently.

So I came across the [synclient command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108587/how-do-i-disable-touchpad-corner-functionalities-e-g-copy-paste-context-ri). However, the command is obviously reset every time I restart.

So I wanted them to [stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290009/how-do-i-make-my-synclient-settings-stick).
However, it didn't work I also tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/126539/73423). I finally grew exasperated and tried to put in session and startup which failed. It did n't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the right solution after a lot of searching and trial and error. The sleep command is crucial. It waits for the synclient to load. I so far put it to 100 seconds of waiting time before running the command. Perhaps, a shorter wait time could work but for now it

```
/usr/bin/synclient RTCornerButton="0"
/usr/bin/synclient RTCornerButton="0"
/usr/bin/synclient RBCornerButton="0"
/usr/bin/synclient TapButton3="0"
/usr/bin/synclient TapAndDragGesture="0"
```

Alternatively, xinput can be used and the command can be inserted in the startup however, an example is as follows to disable the middle button

`xinput set-button-map "11" "1" "1" "1"`